# Wildfly App - can't serve static content

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm working on a Wildfly App project and I'm facing a problem.
I have my web.xml configured and in the webapp folder I have a index.html file.
At first the page worked page and everytime I went to: "localhost/myapp/" it showed me the page.
But arbitrarily the server decided to not provide me the page anymore, and now everytime I try to access the page I get a blank page.
I get a blank page even if I try to go to the resource directly:
"localhost/myapp/index.html".

In the console I have this stack trace:

```
15:50:19,729 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-12) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/jboss-helloworld-html5/
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:75)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:445)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:257)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:194)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Web.xml:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use RESTful/RESTEasy as JBoss seems to think your application is a RESTFul app?

Comment: I'm using restful/resteasy servlets, based on the "jboss-helloworld-html5" example. Do you need other file?

Comment: Can you update your question with the web.xml content?  Did you make any modifications thus far to jboss-helloworld-html5, I was going to say I could try it out - note I am using JBoss EAP 7 but its based on WildFly 10 I believe

Comment: Updated. No, not so many, just added imported some packages and created a new restful service, but this problem started at the very beginning.

Comment: I'm guessing but pretty sure this is whats causing it `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` thats basically saying I want everything to map (be sent) to that servlet so the welcome file list is likely overwritten.  Try being more specific with the URL to the servlet like `<url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>` - let me find you an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your URL pattern is gobbling up everything including the request for a static html page.  Your web.xml should look like this, note "hello" can be changed to anything you like but must match what you place in the browser so the address in the browser would be http://localhost:8080/hello/

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <!-- One of the ways of activating REST Services is adding these lines.
         The server is responsible for adding the corresponding servlet automatically.
         The class org.jboss.as.quickstarts.html5rest.HelloWorld class has the
         annotation @Path("/") to receive the REST invocation -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The static file would likely be accessible with:

http://localhost:8080/

or

http://localhost:8080/index.html